# Customers grid issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

whenever i select more then 20 records from the filter in the magento admin customer->all customers i have seen this issue 
http://prntscr.com/n73cu6
I have tried and i can revert the filter to 20 but when i click on seeing the next 20 customers i face this issue again . is there any way to fix this issue ? I have tried almost every thing every single thing from the google help all commands are done indexer,upgrade,static-content etc every thing .

Comment: does your customer grid having custom/additional column ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below git commit. Hope it will help you
https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/14905